# Fastlane dSYM upload_firebase_app_distribution vs upload_symbols_to_crashlytics

Tags: firebase, fastlane

I am using `upload_firebase_app_distribution` to upload my app to firebase distribution. Do I need to use `upload_symbols_to_crashlytics` to upload dSYMs or this is already handled by `upload_firebase_app_distribution`?